# Copy and paste a shape containing UTF-8 text boxes from Office Word to Paint

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, copy-paste

In Microsoft Office 2010 I have a shape containing UTF-8 textboxes,
when I copy this shape and paste it into MS Paint or any other software, the encoding of texts changes to some vague characters

How can I copy and paste it while preserving the encoding of texts

Comment: Are you sure you copied the textbox itself, not the lines of text inside it? I tried copying a unicode-textbox from Word to Paint, I got no problem.

Comment: @Sanny I copeid a shape containing several textboxes and rectangles, arrows...etc, while the text boxes contained some text in Arabic scripts...

Comment: I used Arial in Word and pasted some Arabic lorem ipsum text to Paint. Still no problem. http://i.imgur.com/UN2mMzu.png. Try working in a new document and use a common font in Windows like Arial or Times New Roman